# Object does not support property or method ForEach Loop

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

Hi I'm trying to iterate through worksheets of a workbook using a For Each loop. My code is pretty simple:

```
Dim visualsBook As Workbook
Set visualsBook = ThisWorkbook
For Each ws In visualsBook
   /action
Next
```

However I keep getting an "Object does not support property or method" error. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Try `For Each ws In visualsBook.Worksheets` assuming that you declared `ws As Worksheet`

Comment: @arcadeprecinct: That is a valid answer. You may want to put it down as such? :)

Comment: I don't understand why everyone puts answers in comments on this forum. Is there some real reason or is it just habit?

Comment: it's just a habit for answers that are really short (for me). I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @jamheadart: `Is there some real reason or is it just habit?` None of those reasons actually. Sometimes I also do it. I don't know about others, but I do it because of sheer laziness :P... And sometimes because the answer is so obvious that I do not want to write a good lenghty quality post for it ;)

Comment: Ha, fair enough. It makes sense to just stick a short answer or a "try this" in the comments, but then it also makes sense to make sure to provide a definitive answer someone can vote up on, so it's all Kosher, marked as resolved.

Comment: @jamheadart when I write an answer I kind of vouch for it to be a solution to the problem. For example I will try the code myself to verify it gives the same error message. In a comment I make no such promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workbook is not a collection that you can loop through. Use `visualsBook.Worksheets` instead.

```
For Each ws In visualsBook.Worksheets
   /action
Next
```

edit: `visualsBook.Sheets` contains charts as well as worksheets so better use `.Worksheets`

Comment: You can also use `.sheets` instead of `.worksheets` if you like to save a nearly infinite amount of time cutting out four letters :D

Comment: @jamheadart: I hope you are aware of the difference between sheets and worksheets? :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout se, this is why I only wrote a comment, now I had to learn something new!

Comment: @SiddharthRout Actually I'm not really, I'm guessing using `.sheets` isn't always going to produce the same result as `.worksheets` then :/

Comment: a worksheet is a sheet that works hard duh... alright sorry, but thanks guys  that was the problem.